# PHP Bootstrap Pagination not working because of data json encode

Tags: php, mysql, json, bootstrap-4, pagination

having a problem with this code

html div

```
<div class="table-container table-responsive-sm  m-5">
  <table class="table table-hover mx-auto" style="width: 100%;" id="table"
    data-show-export="true"
    data-pagination="true"
    data-side-pagination="server"
    data-click-to-select="true"
    data-toolbar="#toolbar"
    data-pagination-v-align="both"
    data-show-toggle="true"
    data-show-columns="true"
    data-url="**json.php**">
  </table>
</div>
```

the pagination is not working look this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPEF0.png)

then when i replay json.php with https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data
it works fine with the pagination
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiWdQ.png)

my json code:

```
    header('Content-type: text/javascript');
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $row_array['id'] = $row['phar_id'];
        $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
        $row_array['batch'] = $row['batch_no'];
        $row_array['category'] = $row['category'];
        $row_array['measurement'] = $row['measurement'];
        $row_array['stock'] = $row['stock'];
        $row_array['price'] = $row['price'];
        $row_array['date'] = $row['date_added'];
        $row_array['expiration'] = $row['expiration_date'];
        $row_array['type'] = $row['medicin_type'];
        $row_array['supplier'] = $row['supplier'];
        $data[] = $row_array; //Same as array_push($data,$row_array);
    }
    
    $final_data = array(
        'total' => count($data),
        'totalNotFiltered' => count($data),
        'rows' => $data,
    );
    
    $convert = json_encode($final_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo $convert;

script code:

<script>
  var $table = $('#table')

  $(function() {
    $('#toolbar').find('select').change(function () {
      $table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({
        exportDataType: $(this).val(),
        exportTypes: ['json', 'xml', 'csv', 'txt', 'sql', 'excel', 'pdf'],
        columns: [
          {
            field: 'state',
            checkbox: true,
            visible: $(this).val() === 'selected'
          },
          {
            field: 'id',
            title: 'ID'
          }, 
          {
            field: 'name',
            title: 'Name'
          },
          {
            field: 'batch',
            title: 'Batch Number'
          },
          {
            field: 'category',
            title: 'Category'
          },
          {
            field: 'measurement',
            title: 'Measurement'
          },
          {
            field: 'stock',
            title: 'Stock'
          },
          {
            field: 'price',
            title: 'Price'
          },
          {
            field: 'date',
            title: 'Date Added'
          },
          {
            field: 'expiration',
            title: 'Expiration Date'
          },
          {
            field: 'type',
            title: 'Medicine Type'
          },
          {
            field: 'supplier',
            title: 'Supplier Name'
          }
        ]
      })
    }).trigger('change')
  })
</script>
```

Here is the bootstrap reference:
https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#extensions/export.html

Comment: you need to use double equals in while loops

Comment: @MetByrdy error on json.php says <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: row in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\himsystem\admin\json.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />

Comment: @MetByrdy no that's a pattern in php when getting rows from mysqli

Comment: pardon me it has been long time I didn't used mysqli :)